# Enable Flexbox Grid in Bootstrap 4 Using NPM

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, sass, flexbox

I have just been testing Bootstrap 4 and for some reason I can't get the Flexbox Grid to be enabled.

Here is my basic SCSS project structure just incase this matters:

```
styles
├── framework
│   ├── vendor
│   │   ├── _bootstrap.scss
│   │
│   ├── _custom.scss
│
├── main.scss
```

I am importing all of my Bootstrap SASS files from NPM into a basic `_bootstrap.scss` file:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.4 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

// Core variables and mixins
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/custom";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/normalize";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/print";

// Core CSS
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";

// Components
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/animation";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/input-group";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tags";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/jumbotron";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/media";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/responsive-embed";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/close";

// Components w/ JavaScript
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/carousel";

// Utility classes
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

I also have a `_custom.scss` that sits outside the vendor folder where bootstrap is placed:

```
// Bootstrap overrides
//
// Copy variables from `_variables.scss` to this file to override default values
// without modifying source files.

$enable-flex:               true;
```

As you can see the `_custom.scss` file contains the `$enable-flex` variable and is set as true.

I then have this `main.scss` file that ties everything together like so:

```
// Bootstrap Vendor Imported From NPM
@import "framework/vendor/bootstrap";
// Custom Variables For Bootstrap
@import "framework/custom";
```

When I try and use the grid everything is still set as floats and my _custom.scss file hasn't enabled the flex grid.

If I change the `_custom.scss` within the NPM bootstrap package folder the grid is enabled however I can't use this as a solution as if someone else uses my project and runs NPM this will be overridden.

Any suggestion on why this might not be working would be great thanks.